# How to mask an animated layer in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

**After effects** noob here. I'm working on an animation where a ball falls through a hole. I created a `Shape layer` to use as the mask, but I can't get it to mask the ball layer.

I've also tried adding a mask directly to the ball layer, but it moves with the rest of the animation. Is there a way to turn the mask on and off without affecting the rest of the animation?

[image: Ball not being masked]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this post helpful: [Preventing a Mask From Animating](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/704283)

> 1. Create a comp size solid above your text layer.
> 2. Apply the mask to the solid.
> 3. Set the **Track Matte** setting of your text layer to `Alpha Matte`.
> 4. The text layer will now adopt the alpha channel of the masked solid.
>
> You can freely animate the text and mask independently.

I did not know the name of what I was trying to do. I needed to convert the mask layer into a `Track Matte`.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, I generally precompose the layer and apply the mask to the precomp (the layer is animating inside the precomp)